# programming/coding and polynomials

Tags: computational-mathematics, symmetric-polynomials

I would like to know your opinion about which is the best code
to work with mathematical operations/structures.

I am doing my thesis on symmetric polynomials and I would like
to include a computational part. Now I am trying to compute 
Schur functions, but C is not the best code to do so. What do you
think?

When I talk about programming, I mean to do like a console application where you can ask someone to put an input and things like that.

Comment: People try to convince me to use [Python](https://www.learnpython.org/). It's not for me but it is apparently very popular in math circles.

Comment: $\displaystyle\texttt{C++}$.

Comment: I really like http://www.sagemath.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to MAGMA? There seem to be a number of functions related to what you have in mind here at https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1762.

Of course, MAGMA comes at a cost, though your institution may have paid the license. SAGE math is free, has a similar amount of functionality, and seems also to have functions of this kind built in: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/sf/schur.html

The best way to run MAGMA is via a Jupyter notebook, while SAGE works best via https://cocalc.com/

Good luck!

Comment: Up to my understanding, there is a deal with Simons foundation which will cover the cost of using MAGMA for all US non-profit, non-governmental scientific research and educational institutions. For those lucky students in US, it is very likely they already have free access to MAGMA.

Comment: And what about Matlab?

Comment: It's not something I use at all, but I know some people (particularly those whose research is of the more Applied kind) use it regularly. For what you have in mind, I doubt Matlab would be the way to go, but like I say I'm no expert on that.